# Is there a clean way to get the number of displayed rows EXCLUDING displayed detail (aka, children) rows in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Previously, I have used `this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()`. However, I recently implemented a Master/Detail record structure for one of my grids and I have found that `getDisplayedRowCount()` is counting the children Detail records as displayed rows.

For example, if I have a table that contains 10 rows, then `this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()` would return 10. Displaying the Details for one of the rows increases that return value to 11.

This isn't behavior that I want, so is there a way to just get the displayed rows, excluding detail rows?

Looking through the gridApi object, I have found a way to do it, but I don't really like that I am accessing nested objects without using the provided API.

`this.gridApi.rowModel.rowsToDisplay.filter(row => !row.detail).length;` -> 10

Answer (score 1):

[`gridApi.forEachNode()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/accessing-data/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNode) and [`gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/accessing-data/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNodeAfterFilter) both appear to skip detail rows while iterating thru row data, so for now, this is the approach that I am following to get this data.

I have replaced my gridApi call to get the displayed row count with a custom function to count the nodes we visit using `forEachNodeAfterFilter`..

```js
  getDisplayedRowCount(){
    let count = 0;
    this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter(() => count++);
    return count;
  }
```